Passing Airflow's execution date to DBTCloud
I am running DBTCloud transformation from Airflow. Job invocation is done as follows:
trigger_job = DbtCloudRunJobOperator(
    task_id="trigger_dbt_cloud_job",
    dbt_cloud_conn_id=DBT_CLOUD_CONN_ID,
    job_id=JOB_ID,
    check_interval=600,
    timeout=3600,
)

I am wondering how I can pass Airflow's execution to DBT script. I will appreciate if anybody can share a sample code.

From what I observed DbtCloudRunJobOperator is a wrapper of DBT Cloud API and there are no arguments for passing parameters compared to CLI implementation. See - https://docs.getdbt.com/dbt-cloud/api-v2#/operations/Trigger%20Job%20Run
Plus, spotted into open issue on DBT resource - https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/job-parameterization-through-dbt-api/12206
